# NextJs 3rd Party Scripts dosen't work when using next/link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**Hello,**
so im refactoring an html project to nextjs app , I have some 3rd party scripts like'jquery.min.js' ,'slick.js' and custom js files ..
I'm loading those files using `<Script  src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>` from `next/script` the issue is that when I use Link from nextjs to switch pages the slick functions won't work , its only work when I do hard refresh
*heres the code from home page index.js*

```
  <Script
    src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"
    strategy="beforeInteractive"
   
  />
  <Script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
  <Script src="assets/js/slick.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
  <Script
    src="assets/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"
    strategy="beforeInteractive"
  />
  <Script src="assets/js/wow.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
  <Script src="assets/js/functions.js" strategy="afterInteractive" />

  <MainSlider images={slider_images} />
  <HomeAbout />
  <HomeDegital />
  <HomeInfluencer />
  <HomeEsport />
  <HomeSpeak />
  <HomePlatforms />
  <HomeCapmpaign />
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    //The Content of function.js in here
    `,
  }}
></script>
```